# Moved Wordpress Correctly (I think) but always get 500 error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am a web developer and often have to create a copy of a client's site on my own server for dev purposes. Everytime I move a site I get an error, either a blank page or a 500 error.

I followed the steps here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Basically I:

1. Downloaded my site files.
2. Exported my database.
3. Edited the wp-config.php with the new server's MySQL database name, user and
   password.
4. Uploaded the files.
5. Imported the database on the new server.
6. Changed the *siteurl* and *home* entries in *wp_options* table to match the new url on my server.
7. Visited to site to see a 500 error.

This didn't work, so I deleted the wp-config.php file and tried to run the automated install by visiting the site. It accepted the database info (connecting) and when I hit run it said that it was already installed and to clear the database tables to install again. I obviously don't want to do this.

So what am I missing? I haven't gotten this to work in a few months if not years and always end up creating a new WP install and importing all the data from the old site via WordPress' importer. In this case I can't because the old site is broken.

The current site I am trying to get to work is at: http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/cancerhope/.

Comment: It would be good if you could check your server log as this will give you more info relating to the error. For example, it might be something in your functions php file. You could post the error from the log to help us track it down

Comment: Thanks, it was a plugin that was throwing an error. The site came up now!

Comment: Cool, that's great

Comment: @MattM - consider posting your own solution as an answer and accepting it, so others may see it. Sounds like your solutions was to check some log file to uncover an issue?

Answer (score 0):

So I checked the error log files and saw that there was a plugin that wasn't allowing the site to be seen. I removed that plugin via FTP and the site came up just fine.

Thanks Luke P for your input!